# SQL Convert Variable Value into Readable Code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

Is the following possible?

```
DECLARE @Something

SET @Something = 'FROM tb'

SELECT tb.*
@Something
```

Further more, if it is possible, do you cast, convert or what the variable to allow this to happen?

Let me clarify, I am using PIVOT to switch up the rows to column for one of my queries. If I have a variable @Something whose value is Item1,Item1,Item2,Item3. Can I use this variable in the SELECT area of my query?

For example:

```
DECLARE @Something AS VARCHAR

SET @Something = 'Item1,Item1,Item2,Item3' 

SELECT @Something 

FROM tb
```

Comment: Yes it is called dynamic SQL. **[Curse and Blessings](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)** Before you go this path, think twice :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @something NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET     @something = N'SELECT * FROM tb'
EXEC    sp_executesql @something
```